# Flutter issue with NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, scrollable

Hey there I am trying to work my way through building a 2 tabs page with a nested scrollable action in each tab. It seems that I am nearly there but still missing something. Using the following code, I am not able to scroll the result:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (queryNews != null) {
      final List<String> _tabs = ['News', 'Articles'];
      return DefaultTabController(
        length: _tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                  handle:
                      NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                  sliver: SliverAppBar(
                    pinned: true,
                    forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      tabs:
                          _tabs.map((String name) => Tab(text: name)).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: TabBarView(
              children: _tabs.map((String name) {
                return SafeArea(
                  top: false,
                  bottom: false,
                  child: Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return CustomScrollView(
                        key: PageStorageKey<String>(name),
                        slivers: <Widget>[
                          SliverOverlapInjector(
                            handle:
                                NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                                    context),
                          ),
                          SliverPadding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                              itemExtent: 80.0,
                              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                                  );
                                },
                                childCount: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

However, If I change the childCount to 30, it becomes scrollable. This is quite weird, any help is appreciated.
Flutter Doctor is clean no issues

Comment: Hi @Moni, I ran your code on dartPad and it seems to be scrolling on 15 items also. Can you try flutter clean and re-run your app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that with no luck. I am using the flutter emulator on vs code for that